# R - Use an outlier function on a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, function, outliers

I've made an outlier function and would like to apply it to a list of dataframes. So far unsuccessfully. Is this a job for lapply, or sapply?

```
# Remove outliers
outlier <- function(x) {
  x[x < quantile(x,0.25) - 6 * IQR(x) | x > quantile(x,0.75) + 6 * IQR(x)] <- NA
  x
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the `list` of `data.frame`, then the function is applied on each column by looping over the columns (`lapply`) and assign the output back

```
lapply(lst1, function(x) {x[] <- lapply(x, outlier)
                     x })
```

If the columns are of mixed types, we select the numeric columns and apply the function

```
lapply(lst1, function(x) {i1 <- sapply(x, is.numeric)
             x[i1] <- lapply(x[i1], outlier)
             x
      })
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(lst1 ~ .x %>%
             mutate_if(is.numeric, outlier))
```

Comment: Thanks! and how to refer to the column names?

Comment: @Brad  didn't get your question.  Did you meant to subset the columns and apply

Comment: It produces this error message " Error in (1 - h) * qs[i] : non-numeric argument to binary operator "

Comment: @Brad It's beacuse there are non-numeric columns.

Comment: @Brad try with `mutate_if` with an additional check

Comment: Yes I have factors and numeric, but only want to apply it to the numeric columns in each df. Thanks Akrun.